# Integrate HttpWatch with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, httpwatch

I use Selenium IDE to record test cases for our project. We are planning to use HttpWatch for monitoring the performance of our site.
Is there any way we can integrate both Selenium IDE and Httpwatch together so that whenever we run Selenium Test case, Httpwatch should also start recording simultaneously.

Awaiting replies :)

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Can you please describe in more details?

Answer (score 0):

HttpWatch 8.4 has improved support for Selenium and some code samples:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2012/07/17/httpwatch-8-4-supports-firefox-14-and-selenium/